# Groovy Spock BlockingVariable never released

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy, spock

I am fighting a loosing battle against Spock unit tests in my Grails application. I want to test async behavior and in order to get familiar with Spock's `BlockingVariable` I've written this simple sample test.

```
void "test a cool function of my app I will not tell you about"() {
    given:
    def waitCondition = new BlockingVariable(10000)
    def runner = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        void run() {
            Thread.sleep(5000)
            waitCondition.set(true)
        }
    }

    when:
    new Thread(runner)

    then:
    true == waitCondition.get()
}
```

Unfortunately it is not a good thing, because otherwise it would come to an end. When I set a breakpoint at `Thread.sleep()` and debug the test, that breakpoint is never hit. What am I missing?

Comment: You can use (in Groovy) `Thread.start { waitCondition.set(true) }` to help avoid this sort of error, as you don't need to remember the call to `run()` :-)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to keep that in mind for future nonsense tests :) Using `Thread` isn't the goal here, it was just a means to an end to test `BlockingVariable`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your test is broken, because you don't actually run the thread you create. Instead:

```
when:
new Thread(runner)
```

you should do:

```
when:
new Thread(runner).run()
```

and then your test succeeds after approximately 5 seconds.

Comment: Ugh, how did I miss that? Thanks. I'll go slap myself on the fingers three times for this stupid mistake.